# Execute class level functions dynamically

Tags: ruby, class, module, eval, metaprogramming

actually the question is about my misunderstanding of ruby meta programming: just want to clear my questions here:
I have a working code in one of my module like:

```
module Mappable
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval do
      class << self
        attr_accessor :source
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My understanding of what happens here is: on whatever class that includes the Mappable module  we want evaluate code "attr_accessor :source".

What then the "class << self" here for? If we already evaluate "attr_accessor :source" with "klass.class_eval"
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that should help explain what's going on here. I will shortly add some explanatory remarks.

```
module Mappable
  def self.included(klass)
    puts "klass = #{klass}"
    puts "self before class_eval = #{self}"
    klass.class_eval do
      puts "self after class_eval and before class << self = #{self}"
      class << self
        puts "self after class << self = #{self}"
        attr_accessor :source
      end
    end
  end
end

class A
  include Mappable
  attr_accessor :source
  @source = 'cat'
  def initialize
    @source = 'dog'
  end
end
```

Here is the result of `Mappable` being `include`d in `A`:

```
#-> klass = A
#-> self before class_eval = Mappable
#-> self after class_eval and before class << self = A
#-> self after class << self = #<Class:A>
```

It is seen that `klass.class_eval` (`A.class_eval`) changes the context (value of `self`) from `Mappable` to `A`. `class << self` (`class << A`) then changes the context to `A`'s singleton class, which is were we execute the method `attr_accessor` to create the read-write accessor for the class instance variable `@source`.

```
A.methods(false)
  #=> [:source, :source=]
A.instance_variables 
  #=> [:@source]

A.source
  #=> "cat"
A.source = 'pig'
A.source
  #=> "pig"
```

This shows that the accessor we have created for the class instance variable `@a` appears to be working properly. Now let's look at the instance methods and instance variable.

```
A.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:source, :source=]
a = A.new
  #=> #<A:0x000001018fdc78 @source="dog">
a.instance_variables
  #=> [:@source]
a.source
  #=> "dog"
a.source = 'cow'
  #=> "cow"
a.source
  #=> "cow"
```

That seems OK as well. It is important to understand that while `A` and `a` each has an instance variable `@source`, the two variables are unrelated.  Lastly, let's confirm that in changing the value of the instance variable we did not affect the value of the class instance variable:

```
A.source
  #=> "pig"
```

There are other ways to change the context to `A`'s singleton class, in order to execute the method `attr_accessor`. I'm rather found of using [Object#singleton_class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class), which has been with us since Ruby 1.9.2:

```
def self.included(klass)
  klass.singleton_class.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :source
  end
end
```

Comment: WOw, gosh, thank you! Looking forward for updates but this itself is a great explanation